# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}(-1)^{n}$ converges or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

From other questions we could know the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}$ converges (using the Euler equaiton) and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin n|}{n}$ diverges (using the Euler–Maclaurin formula), but how to prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}(-1)^{n}$ converges or not? I can not find some useful techniques. I hope some help, I am very grateful!!!

Comment: Using the Abel-Plana formula, c.f: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula, we have $\sum_{n\geqslant 1} (-1)^{n}\frac{\sin n}{n}=-1+\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(-1){\rm sinc}(n)=-1+\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, the series converges.

Comment: $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\sin nx}{n}=-\Im \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{e^{inx}}{n}=-\Im \ln(1+e^{ix})=-\Im \ln(2\cos\frac{x}{2}e^{i\frac{x}{2}})=-\frac{x}{2}$
$$S(x=1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\sin n}{n}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav One should note that this formula breaks for $x\not\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: @user. Yes, this is correct. Thank you for this valuable point!

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thanks for your answer and I want to know what theorem used in your first equation? I am not very familiar with that.

Comment: Hanyi Young What formula you are interested in?

Comment: @Svyatoslav What does J mean in your first equation, I don't know the related formula...

Comment: Hanyi Young This means to take the imaginary part: $ \Im e^{inx}=\sin nx$

Answer (score 0):

We are goibg to use Dirichlet's criteria for series. Let:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}$$
This is a decreasing sequence and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=0$.
Now, let: $$b_n=(-1)^n\cdot\sin(n)$$
We have to show that the sum:
$$S_M=\sum_{i=0}^{M}(-1)^i\cdot \sin(i)$$
is bounded. Or, there is a $K$ indipendent from $M$, such that:
$$\left|\sum_{i=0}^{M}(-1)^i\cdot \sin(i)\right|\leq K$$

Multiply the sum by $2\sin(1)$:
$$2\sin(1)\cdot S_M=2\sin(1)\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{M}(-1)^i\cdot \sin(i)$$

Using the indentity $2\sin(a)\sin(b)=\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)$, we have:

$$2\sin(1)\cdot S_M=\sum_{i=0}^{M}(-1)^i\cdot\left(\cos(1-i)-\cos(1+i)\right)$$

Expanding some terms:
$$i=0\implies \cos(1)-\cos(1)$$
$$i=1\implies -\cos(0)+\cos(2)$$
$$i=2\implies \cos(1)-\cos(3)$$
$$i=3\implies -\cos(2)+\cos(4)$$

We have a telescopic sum. In particular, it converges to:
$$2\sin(1)\cdot S_M=\cos(1)-\cos(0)+\cos(M+1)-\cos(M-1)\implies \left|S_M\right|\leq \frac{2}{\sin(1)}=K$$

Thus, the series converges by Dirichlet criteria.

Comment: Also, if you want to have a similar proof, you can see this video: https://youtu.be/27ScfH-9ndo.